# Writing to a file in R prints on 2 lines

Tags: r

I am writing a vector to a file in R. However the output comes on 2 lines. I wanted all the values to come on a single line. Can you let me know how to fix this

```
write(value,file=fileconn,append=TRUE,sep="\t")
```

The o/p comes as follows

1777.167    1825.167    1873.167    1921.167    1969.167

2017.167

Regards
Ganesh

Comment: can you please provide `dput(value)`

Comment: That's what I was going to suggest too `cat(value, file = "filename")` might be better.  And then you can use `scan` to read it back in.  I'm also curious to know what `fileconn` is.  Is that a connection?

Comment: @Mr.Flick Thanks. I did not realize that write had a ncolumns parameter. I did check on other vectors and I did notice that it defaulted to 5 columns. I added ncolumns and it is fine write(value,file=fileconn,append=TRUE,sep="\t",ncolumns=7)

Comment: @Richard the file columns is a connection fileconn <-file(filename)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure `write()` is probably not the best choice, but if you want to use it, it might be a good idea to check the `?write` help file. It does have an `ncolumns=` parameter which defaults to 5 for simple numeric vectors.

I would think `cat()` would be a better solution for just dumping numeric vectors.